# ggplot how to fill one price value with different color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code

```
      ggplot(xdata) + 
           geom_histogram(aes(price),fill = 'orange',alpha = 0.85,binwidth = 15) + 
           theme_minimal(base_size = 13) + xlab("Price") + ylab("Frequency") + 
           ggtitle("The Distrubition of Price")+ xlim(0,5000)
```

the result is

[image]

I need help to turn any bar in my plot that is less than $150 to a different color, any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `ggplot2::diamonds` dataset as example data this could be achieved via an `ifelse` and making use of `scale_fill_manual` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(price, fill = ifelse(price < 1500, "low", "high")),alpha = 0.85,binwidth = 15) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(low = "steelblue", high = "orange")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 13) + xlab("Price") + ylab("Frequency") + 
  ggtitle("The Distrubition of Price")+ xlim(0,5000)
#> Warning: Removed 14714 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
p <- ggplot(xdata)

p + 
  geom_histogram(aes(price, color = ifelse(price < 1500, "< $150", ">= $150")),
                 alpha = 0.85, binwidth = 15) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("< $150" = "green", ">= $150" = "orange")) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 13) + 
  xlab("Price") + 
  ylab("Frequency") + 
  ggtitle("The Distrubition of Price") + 
  xlim(0,5000)
```